# Open popup in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js rendered in HTML which would give a preview of the form. The code is functioning correctly but it gives me the output on the same page rather i want to open it in a pop-up window. I have tried using window.open () with no luck. Could you please help me out in how i can use window.open() for the below. The button ID is preview. When the button is clicked it executes a function similar to below

```
$("#preview").click(function() {

    $("#formpreview").delete();
    var fieldSet = ...................});
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried, and add more specifically what didn't work about it? A lot of browsers, for instance have pop blockers for non-trusted user actions

Answer (score 0):

You can populate the html in the child window using the below example:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE Html />
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="button" id="launch" value="Launch Child Window"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="theJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var btnLaunch = document.getElementById("launch");

btnLaunch.onclick = function () {
    var childWindow = window.open("", "", "height=500, width=500");
    var html = "";
    var theVariable = "Conent in Child Window";
    html += "<p>" + theVariable + "</p>";
    childWindow.document.body.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the popup as a variable, then set the popup's HTML to whatever you need.

```
$("#preview").click(function() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "Popup", "width=300, height=500");
    myWindow.document.write("<html>This is where your content goes</html>");
});
```

Comment: You should avoid using `document.write()` as much as humanly possible!

Comment: I don't see the issue, he's creating a blank popup from scratch and is (potentially) including stylesheets, scripts, etc.